# Capture frame in opencv camera and intent

Tags: opencv, android-intent, android-camera-intent, android

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override    
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onTouch event");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    String saveDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/DCIM/OCV/TouchSave";
    File dirCheck = new File(saveDir);
    if(!dirCheck.exists()) {
        dirCheck.mkdirs();
    }
    String fileName = saveDir + "/touch_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
    try {
        mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);

        Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    last_photo_name = fileName;

    return false;
}
```

This is my current touchscreen capture function for and opencv Library camera.This works fine and can save the image to sdcard.
**However, I also hope to intent the activity after capturing the photo. The final result is that it cannot capture the photo (I have checked my storage) but can intent to another activity.**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(ShowCameraViewActivity.this,CaptureActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("path", last_photo_name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the line of code that I added. 
**Can anyone help me to add these lines of code but it can also capture the photo? Thank You very much.**

Also, I got another questions. **I added a button on the opencv cameraview but I cannot add the above capture function on the onClick function. How can I add them into the onClick function??Thank You very much.**